# How can I get a CKEditor value?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ckeditor

I have this input field in my view:

```
<div class="treatment-service">
  <%= f.input :service_id, as: :select, collection: current_partner.services.pluck(:name, :id), :label => "Serviciu" %>
</div>
<%= f.input :description, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Pure'}}%>
```

and this function in my treatments.js file, where I autocomplete details based on the value selected in the dropdown select.

```
var serviceDetails = function (){
  $('.treatment-service').change(function(){
      var service_id = $(this).find('select').val();
      debugger
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: "/treatment_services/"+service_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          debugger
        $('.treatment-service').closest('div').next().find('input').val(data.price)
        $('.treatment-service').closest('div').next().next().find('input').val(data.unit)
        }
      })
    });
}
```

controller:

```
  def service_details
    render json: current_partner.services.find(params[:service_id])
  end
```

route:

```
get '/treatment_services/:service_id' => 'treatments#service_details'
```

But how can I get the instance value from inside the ckeditor field?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand fully, but you can get the value of a CKEditor instance via:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['div_id'].getData() // the div id without a #
```